# Passing instance variables to DSL based on instance eval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dsl, instance-variables, proc

I'm trying to write a DSL to wrap Mongoid's aggregation pipeline (i.e. Mongo DB).

I've made a module that when included, adds a class method that accepts a block, which it hands to an object that passes requests to Mongoid (via method missing).

So I can do:

```
class Project
  include MongoidAggregationHelper
end

result = Project.pipeline do
  match dept_id: 1
end

#...works!
```

"match" is a method on Mongoid's aggregation pipeline, which is intercepted and passed on.

BUT instance variables set outside the block are not available, since its being executed in the context of the proxy class.

```
dept_id = 1

result = Project.pipeline do
  match dept_id: dept_id
end

#...fails, dept_id not found :(
```

Any way to pass/redefine external instance variables in with the block?

Below is the trimmed code:

```
module MongoidAggregationHelper
  def self.included base
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def pipeline &block
      p = Pipeline.new self
      p.instance_eval &block
      return p.execute
    end
  end

  class Pipeline
    attr_accessor :cmds, :mongoid_class
    def initialize klass
      self.mongoid_class = klass
    end

    def method_missing name, opts={}
      #...proxy to mongoid...
    end

    def execute
      #...execute pipeline, return the results...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you try `def pipeline(*args, &block)` and `Project.pipeline dept_id: dept_id do`?

Comment: Good suggestion @MrYoshiji, in the production code I do that and it works.  I would like to avoid having to pass the variables in as an options hash however, and use the previously declared variables if theres some what to do it.

Comment: I posted an answer with an alternative

Comment: Hi juwiley, I did not find `match` method in Mongoid. Can you please tell me where did you find this method?

Comment: @Kuldeep its buried deep within the Mongoid driver.  Thats the rationale for writing this wrapper, one day Mongoid will/should expose the API in a cleaner way.  You can get to it via YourModel.collection.aggregate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following: (**unlimited amount of arguments**, kinda have to use a Hash)

```
# definition
def pipeline(*args, &block)
  # your logic here
end

# usage
dept_id = 1
result = Project.pipeline(dept_id: dept_id) do
  match dept_id: dept_id
end
```

---

Or you can use named arguments, **if you know how many arguments** you need to execute the DSL:

```
# definition
def pipeline(dept_id, needed_variable, default_variable = false, &block)
  # your logic here
end

# usage
dept_id = 1
result = Project.pipeline(dept_id, other_variable) do
  match dept_id: dept_id
end
```

Comment: Wish I could do this seamlessly without having to pass anything in, but looks like its not possible